# How to parse emojis and convert to images?

Tags: ruby, emoji

I'm sure there is already a ruby gem that supports this...I want to parse a string which could potentially contain an emoji and replace it with an HTML image. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [gemoji-parser](https://github.com/gmac/gemoji-parser).

While many libs provide raw emoji data, they tend to be a bit underwhelming on parsing firepower that actually transforms emoji between symbol types (unicode, tokens, emoticons, images, etc). The above is a parser extension for gemoji data.

Answer (score 2):

[The Emoji gem](https://github.com/steveklabnik/emoji)

The first section [here](https://github.com/steveklabnik/emoji#usage) does what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look at [gemoji](https://github.com/github/gemoji) by the Github team.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the source of [Twemoji](https://github.com/jollygoodcode/twemoji)'s source code, bascially it builds up a huge emoji pattern, match, replace with image.